# UWP and Unpackaged Desktop App Communication

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

I'm attempting to develop an Xbox Game Bar Widget, which obviously needs to be UWP. I need it to communicate with my separate unpackaged desktop app. The regular desktop app has to be unpackaged because it requires admin rights in order to read CPU temperatures.

I've tried using Named Pipes as the Microsoft Docs page suggests, but I'm having issues creating/connecting the pipes on the UWP side. I just keep getting Access Denied exceptions. I've had trouble finding information/examples on interprocess communication between UWP and **unpackaged** apps. Any direction / advice is much appreciated.

Comment: It should be packaged, and if you want to elevate your packaged apps, please refer to stefan'g blog [`App Elevation Samples`](https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/)

Comment: @CoCaIceDew I read somewhere that if an app requires elevation, it will not be accepted to the Microsoft Store. I actually figured out the communication issue. The SID of the packaged game bar app changes every time you click 'Deploy' so the SID I was allowing in the PipeSecurity was always old and wrong.

Comment: Can you use [Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#shared-memory) to share the latest sid for desktop process?